# Sending information from URL to file, PHP

Tags: c#, php

Studying C# and noticed this in a code example:

```
namespace my_program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Url to send username, computer name and computer info
        string targetURL = "https://www.example.com/my_program/write.php?info=";
        string userName = Environment.UserName;
        string computerName = System.Environment.MachineName.ToString();
        string userDir = "C:\\Users\\";
```

I do not know what code write.php consists of on the server. So my question is: In order to save the information provided in the URL, after /write.php?info=, in a textfile on my server, how would I code that in php? I'm sure this is very basic but it is something new to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the `php` file you can use the function [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) or its alias `fputs`.

Assumming your url in `C#` is `https://www.example.com/my_program/write.php?info=WriteThisNow"`

Here's an example that should get you going in `php`

```
<?php

$string = $_GET['info']; // take the value of the GET superglobal

$handle = fopen('output.txt', 'w'); // open a handler to a file for writing
fputs($handle, $string); // write the contents of the $string variable to the file
fclose($handle); // close the handler
```

All you need now is that Apache or Nginx to have write permissions on the filesystem and your file should be created next to the php file with the contents inside.